# Changing my static PHP code to a loop to save time and speed

Tags: php, function, loops, if-statement

I have a shop code that I use to store data and email to the shoppers that I made.
It works great and functions as it should.

The problem is, I coded it without a loop because I didn't know how to do it.

I currently have 5 products limit on it and even now I struggle to edit anything because I have to apply the changes to the 5 parts one by one.

If you can help me change this to a loop it would be a life saver and I can change my products limit to unlimited rather than 5 and will be able to edit the layout quickly.
Any help is appreciated.

```
if ($productname1 != "") {
$message .= "<tr style='background: #F30'><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 24px;text-align: center;'><strong>Product Number 1</strong> </td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Product Name</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $productname1 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Link</strong> </td><td style='font-size:12px;direction:ltr;text-align:center'><strong><a href='" . $link1 . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;'>" . $link1 . "</a></strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Color</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $color1 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Size</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $size1 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Model</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $otherinfo1 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Quantity</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $no1 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Description</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $other1 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Price</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Domestic Shipping</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
if ($delivery == "Extra handling"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Extra handling fee</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
else if ($delivery == "No handling fees"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>No handling fees to  ".$clientcity."</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
}
if ($productname2 != "") {
$message .= "<tr style='background: #F30'><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 24px;text-align: center;'><strong>Product Number 2</strong> </td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Product Name</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $productname2 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Link</strong> </td><td style='font-size:12px;direction:ltr;text-align:center'><strong><a href='" . $link2 . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;'>" . $link2 . "</a></strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Color</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $color2 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Size</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $size2 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Model</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $otherinfo2 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Quantity</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $no2 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Description</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $other2 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Price</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Domestic Shipping</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
if ($delivery == "Extra handling"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Extra handling fee</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
else if ($delivery == "No handling fees"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>No handling fees to  ".$clientcity."</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
}
if ($productname3 != "") {
$message .= "<tr style='background: #F30'><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 24px;text-align: center;'><strong>Product Number 3</strong> </td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Product Name</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $productname3 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Link</strong> </td><td style='font-size:12px;direction:ltr;text-align:center'><strong><a href='" . $link3 . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;'>" . $link3 . "</a></strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Color</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $color3 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Size</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $size3 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Model</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $otherinfo3 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Quantity</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $no3 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Description</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $other3 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Price</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Domestic Shipping</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
if ($delivery == "Extra handling"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Extra handling fee</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
else if ($delivery == "No handling fees"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>No handling fees to  ".$clientcity."</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
}
if ($productname4 != "") {
$message .= "<tr style='background: #F30'><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 24px;text-align: center;'><strong>Product Number 4</strong> </td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Product Name</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $productname4 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Link</strong> </td><td style='font-size:12px;direction:ltr;text-align:center'><strong><a href='" . $link4 . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;'>" . $link4 . "</a></strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Color</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $color4 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Size</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $size4 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Model</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $otherinfo4 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Quantity</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $no4 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Description</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $other4 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Price</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Domestic Shipping</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
if ($delivery == "Extra handling"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Extra handling fee</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
else if ($delivery == "No handling fees"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>No handling fees to  ".$clientcity."</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
}
if ($productname5 != "") {
$message .= "<tr style='background: #F30'><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 24px;text-align: center;'><strong>Product Number 5</strong> </td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Product Name</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $productname5 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Link</strong> </td><td style='font-size:12px;direction:ltr;text-align:center'><strong><a href='" . $link5 . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;'>" . $link5 . "</a></strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Color</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $color5 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Size</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $size5 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Model</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $otherinfo5 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Quantity</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $no5 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Description</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $other5 . "</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Price</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Domestic Shipping</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
if ($delivery == "Extra handling"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Extra handling fee</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
else if ($delivery == "No handling fees"){
$message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>No handling fees to  ".$clientcity."</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: There is a lot more to be done than just the php loop to improve editability... I suggest you start with a clean html template for the shop item. Move styles to external style sheet. For the loop, look into using an `array` for your products and `foreach` to loop through its items.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code of your loop and why it doesn't work! And maybe simplify your question so we don't have to look through a lot of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message = '';

$products = array(
    0 => array( 
        'productname' => $productname1,
        'link' => $link1,
        'color' => $color1,
        'size' => $size1,
        'otherinfo' => $otherinfo1,
        'no' => $no1,
        'other' => $other1
    ),

    1 => array( 
        'productname' => $productname2,
        'link' => $link2,
        'color' => $color2,
        'size' => $size2,
        'otherinfo' => $otherinfo2,
        'no' => $no2,
        'other' => $other2
    ),

    2 => array( 
        'productname' => $productname3,
        'link' => $link3,
        'color' => $color3,
        'size' => $size3,
        'otherinfo' => $otherinfo3,
        'no' => $no3,
        'other' => $other3
    ),

    3 => array( 
        'productname' => $productname4,
        'link' => $link4,
        'color' => $color4,
        'size' => $size4,
        'otherinfo' => $otherinfo4,
        'no' => $no4,
        'other' => $other4
    ),

    4 => array( 
        'productname' => $productname5,
        'link' => $link5,
        'color' => $color5,
        'size' => $size5,
        'otherinfo' => $otherinfo5,
        'no' => $no5,
        'other' => $other5
    ),
);

foreach ($products as $i => $product) {
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #F30'><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 24px;text-align: center;'><strong>Product Number " . ($i +1) . "</strong> </td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Product Name</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $product['productname'] . "</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Link</strong> </td><td style='font-size:12px;direction:ltr;text-align:center'><strong><a href='" . $product['link'] . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;'>" . $product['link'] . "</a></strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Color</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $product['color'] . "</strong></td></tr>";

    $message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Size</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $product['size'] . "</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Model</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $product['otherinfo'] . "</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Quantity</strong> </td><td style='direction:ltr;text-align:right'><strong>" . $product['no'] . "</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Description</strong> </td><td><strong>" . $product['other'] . "</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Price</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #CC0000;'><td><strong>Domestic Shipping</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
    if ($delivery == "Extra handling"){
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>Extra handling fee</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
    }
    else if ($delivery == "No handling fees"){
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #09C;'><td><strong>No handling fees to  ".$clientcity."</strong></td><td><div style='float:left;width:90%;text-align:right;'><strong>$</strong></div><strong>00.00</strong></td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Now there is a strong relationship between the nth item of every array. Wouldn't it be better to create a multi-dimensional array of elements, to keep items that have a relationship together? Or maybe create a `project` object? This is not by far well-written and easy to maintain code, and please don't encourage using it!

Comment: Yes we can do so @Frog. (y)

Comment: So why don't you in your answer?!

Comment: Yes, with the less time interval, I made these. I will definitely change it. Thanks for pointing :)

Comment: The code is almost perfect @Prava-MindfireSolutions but it shows all the products even if the name fields are left empty.
The product name check doesn't work anymore. All 5 products get shown all the time. How to add a check for that?

Comment: added if ($productname[$i] != ''){ } inside the loop and it's done! Thank you @Prava-MindfireSolutions!

Comment: @Frog, I did it :) and I think it is now better than the previous. Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Claudio, thanks for the appreciation, and yes I changed the code a bit and very nice for adding the check inside the loop.

Comment: I changed the code to a foreach loop to make it clearer. Also, you should look into PHP's [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to make the message easier to read. Finally, try to do more using CSS, it will make your code way easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this:

Instead of writing, for example:

```
if ($productname5 != "") {
```

Write:

```
if (${"productname" . $i} != "") {
```

And have a loop with `$i` adding one each time. Tell me if you need help on that.

You can do this with every other variable, and voila! You have a working loop on this code.

Comment: Where do I make the $i go up by one? at the beginning or the end of the loop?

Comment: @ClaudioDelgado at the beginning, so it goes 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: You could also slice the array to 5 elements and do a `foreach`.

Comment: The form checks if the $productname1 through $productname5 exist so that it can fetch the other details. How do I make it so that it doesn't go up more than the amount of $productname . $i that are available?

Comment: like this: `if ($i > 5) break;`